# Logitech MX Anywhere 2 Mouse "Smooth Scrolling Mode" is Overly Active

Tags: high-sierra, mouse, macos

The mouse has two scroll wheel options. One is incremental, which seems to work fine. This is where the mouse wheel clicks slightly as it's turned. The second mode is more of a fluid scroll, which can be enabled by pressing the mouse wheel down. When I'm in the fluid scroll mode, many apps misbehave. For example, when I view Google Maps the map starts zooming in and out randomly, and random uninitiated scrolling happens in other apps as well, like Acrobat. Using Mac High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E202)

**Update**:

It seems that the problem goes away when I disable smooth scrolling, but this really limits the functionality of the mouse.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with Logitech support?

Comment: Thank you so much for this: "One is incremental, which seems to work fine. This is where the mouse wheel clicks slightly as it's turned.". Now I no longer have the silly after scroll effect.